# How can I add rtf files to Resources in VS 2015/NET 3.5

Tags: vb.net

I am revising a legacy VB.NET program I last worked on years ago. I have many existing .rtf files in my Resources folder.
I've gone to the Project's Properties/Resources, but none of my existing .rtf files are listed there. Adding a new .rtf file there adds it in some other format, and doesn't work for my use

Right clicking any existing .rtf file shows BuildAction = None, and CopyToOutputDirectory = Do not copy. So I'm at a loss, and looking for help.

I have a new .rtf file I want to add, but can't remember how I did it before. I've googled around and can't find an answer. If I manually add it to the folder, it shows in the Solutions folder marked "Pending Add". How do I accomplish that?

There is another file that is already existing there that I update in MSWord and saved back. That shows the edited content when I run the program, but it is marked "Pending edit" in the Solutions folder. How do I do that?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, after posting this question and thinking some more, I thought of something to try and it worked.

I wondered if the markings on the two files in solution explorer were referring to my Git repo, since one used the term "Pending Add". As an experiment, I went back to the Project's Properties/Resources and added my new existing file. Even though the result (an image representation of the file) was not what I expected, I closed that window and did a Git commit. Then the two files in solution explorer had their tags updated to say "Checked In".

I was not expecting VS2015 to be using the local Git repo for its own internal file version control. Strange.